# NGINX error after 'sudo systemctl status nginx' - Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: node.js, nginx, cloud, ubuntu-20.04, system-administration

After trying to add new domains do my ubuntu 20.04 cloud server with nginx and pm2,I created a server block in

> '/etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.ar'

and did the same thing into

> '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.ar'

The next step was to do a link to both files with

> ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/cloud.ktsoftware.ar /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/cloud.ktsoftware.ar

got a error that files already existed

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.ar': File exists
```

in consequence i run to forced the link

> sudo ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/cloud.ktsoftware.ar /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/cloud.ktsoftware.ar

everything appears ok, no error response after that. Then i do

> sudo systemctl status nginx

and got this error:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-07-10 13:47:17 -03; 17min ago
   Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 1287489 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

> below first error paragraph
>
> > Jul 10 13:47:17 vps-2421400-x systemd[1]: nginx.service: Succeeded.
> > Jul 10 13:47:17 vps-2421400-x systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
> > Jul 10 13:47:17 vps-2421400-x systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
> > Jul 10 13:47:17 vps-2421400-x nginx[1287489]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/n>
> > Jul 10 13:47:17 vps-2421400-x nginx[1287489]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
> > Jul 10 13:47:17 vps-2421400-x systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
> > Jul 10 13:47:17 vps-2421400-x systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> > Jul 10 13:47:17 vps-2421400-x systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
> > lines 1-14/14 (END)

"lines 1-14/14 (END)" *

and crashed everything i think.
What is the best way to link the domains server blocks?